# sort list of objects by list of longs

Tags: c#

I have a class model somewhat like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
   long MyModelID { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of `MyModel` objects called `TheListOfModels` and a list of longs called `TheListOfIDs`: I want `TheListOfModels` to be sorted in the same order as `TheListOfIDs`.

What I have in mind is a loop that goes through the `TheListOfIDs` and at each iteration adds the corresponding `TheListOfModels` to a new list called `SortedList` and then reassigns that list to the original `TheListOfModels`.

Is this the best way to do it or is there a linq syntax for this specific operation?

Thanks.

Comment: yes, I know it has orderby; how does orderby work when provided a list to sort against?

Comment: are the TheListOfIDs equal to the MyModelIDs in TheListOfModels? if so, you may want to try this: List<MyModel> sortedList = TheListOfModels.OrderBy(p=>p.MyModelID);

Comment: TheListOfIDs are the same Ids with TheListOfModels?

Comment: yes, they're both equivalent; both are lists of the same longs.

Comment: @CuongLe: yes, the same exact values, just not in the same order.

Comment: one last question, is the TheListOfIDs ordered ascending or descending or are there special cases?

Comment: @tehdoommarine I think the point is that it's neither.  It's some unknown order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This'll do it:

```
var q = (from i in TheListOfIDs
        join m in TheListOfModels on i equals m.MyModelID
        select m).ToList();
```

Comment: Thats just like Cuong Le and L.B solutions, and just as inefficient.

Comment: @YoryeNathan No it's not, linq `join` uses `HashTables` internally.

Comment: Tested my version vs your version: 1000 elements, 10000 iterations: Me - 3.7s vs You - 4.5s. 100000 elements, 100 iterations: Me - 15.7s vs You - 28.6s. Dictionaries are known to be faster than HashTables. The models and ids were randomly distributed in both scenarios.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Well, linq actually uses `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` but both that and `Dictionary<TKey, TElement>` uses a [HashTable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) data structure.

Comment: Dictionary improves HashTable. Anyway, it doesn't really matter what is better in general - the results speak for themselves.

Answer (score 1):

This one isn't too efficient, but it does the trick:

```
List<Model> models = ...
List<long> ids = ...

var dic = models.ToDictionary(x => x.ID, x => x);
var modelsByIds = ids.Select(x => dic[x]).ToList();
```

Comment: better use ToArray and then use the Array.Sort function which take another array as a reference.

Comment: This isn't actually that inefficient.  It just does one pass over each list.  It's not so efficient in terms of memory usage, but memory is cheap...

Comment: Thinking about it, it will be hard to make it more efficient. Dictionaries are awesome like that.

Comment: On the second line, I get an exception "the dictionary doesn't contain the key" error.

Comment: @frenchie By the comments on the question, I understood that the ID's and Models all share same ID's, just in different order.